# Return ref for iterator but const_ref for const_iterator using boost::iterator_facade<>?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-iterators, iterator-facade

I have a class like this,

```
template <typename Node>
class BSTIteratorBase : public boost::iterator_facade<
    BSTIteratorBase<Node>,
    typename Node::value_type,
    boost::forward_traversal_tag
>
{ ...
    value_type& dereference() const
    { return const_cast<value_type&>( nodePtr_->value_ ); } // Ouch! const_iterator may modify
... };
```

`value_type` does not depend on the **constness** of the `BSTNode` class. That is why I had to keep the `const_cast<value_type&>()` part. How can I make sure that `const_iterator` return a `const_ref` but `iterator` returns a modifiable `ref`? Here are the relevant typedefs,

```
template <typename T>
class BinarySearchTree
{
public:
    typedef T                                   value_type;
    typedef T&                                  reference;
    typedef const T&                            const_reference;
    typedef BSTNode<T>                          node_type;    
    typedef BSTNode<T>&                         node_reference;
    typedef BSTNode<T>*                         node_pointer;
    typedef BSTIteratorBase<BSTNode<T>>         iterator;
    typedef BSTIteratorBase<const BSTNode<T>>   const_iterator;
```

And the node class,

```
template <typename T>
class BSTNode
{
public:
    typedef T           value_type;
    typedef T&          reference;
    typedef const T&    const_reference;
    typedef BSTNode     node_type;
    typedef BSTNode*    node_pointer;

    // ctors, dtor

private:
    template <class> friend class BSTIteratorBase;
    template <class> friend class BinarySearchTree;

    T value_;
    node_pointer leftPtr_;
    node_pointer rightPtr_;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [metafunction](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/metafunction.html) that constifies `value_type` if its enclosing type is const:

```
template<class T>
struct ValueTypeOf { 
    typedef typename T::value_type type; 
};

template<class T>
struct ValueTypeOf<T const> {
    typedef typename T::value_type const type; 
};

template <typename Node>
class BSTIteratorBase : public boost::iterator_facade<
    BSTIteratorBase<Node>,
    typename ValueTypeOf<Node>::type,
    boost::forward_traversal_tag
>
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to write

```
typedef BSTIteratorBase<BSTNode<T>>               iterator;
typedef BSTIteratorBase<const BSTNode<const T>>   const_iterator;
                                      ^-- note extra const
```

Note that this nicely mirrors the `T **` -> `const T *const *` transformation.

Comment: Please explain when a transformation of the form `T **` -> `const T *const *` is useful.

Comment: @Hindol when you want to pass a `T **` to a function that doesn't need to modify its argument.  It's [18.17 in the FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/constptrptr-conversion.html).